Is it acceptable to add a "literal" translation to an interlinear gloss?
None of the official guidelines (Leipzig Glossing Rules) and other references I've seen give examples of interlinear glosses that include a line for a literal translation.
In some cases, especially when the morpheme analysis is dense or the object language just uses a completely different structure for some expression, I think it would be useful to provide a literal translation to help the reader understand how the overall structure differs from the metalanguage.
In some books I have seen authors write "lit. <literal translation>", but I don't think I've ever seen it in a gloss. If there is some precedent for this, I'm wondering how it would be formatted.
Here's a simple example of what I'm talking about:
Tengo hambre.
teng-o       hambre
have-1SG.PRS hunger
I'm hungry.
(lit.) I have hunger.


Why wouldn’t it be? I’ve more commonly seen it added before the real translation, though, as an ‘intermediary’ step between the gloss and the meaning in the target language. (Also, splitting tengo as ten-go seems problematic to me… apart from vowelless roots, the 1sg present ending is always -o, while stems often alternate between persons – no need to complicate that by adding additional endings.)

@JanusBahsJacquet Agreed on both counts.

I think it is always "acceptable" to provide information, but what would be a case in which the interlinear gloss does not indicate the literal translation? In your example I find it obvious enough that it is a construction with "have" simply from the gloss.

I have hunger is a literal translation. So, it's there. And then the idiomatic one is given.

My example was intended to be extremely simple and contrived, and I knew people would nitpick it. I tried to look up whether someone would analyze -go or -o as the 1st person singular morpheme in this specific case, and couldn't find anything. Either way made just as much sense to me, since the g is not present in the root word. Regardless, surely you can extrapolate the idea to see how a more complicated phrase in a much different language could become difficult to parse.

@JanusBahsJacquet To your question "why wouldn't it be?" - that's exactly why I'm asking this question. I was wondering how rigid glossing standards are, and whether there's an established norm for this idea specifically.

They’re not very rigid. The Leipzig rules are the most commonly used, but they’re not universal, and while there’s nothing specifically about intermediary verbatim translations, I don’t think they would be considered to go against the Leipzig rules either – they’re just something the rules don’t have an opinion about. (As for the root of tengo, consider that you have at least ten- and tien- in the indicative, plus teng- in the subjunctive, so the root changing within a paradigm is already an established feature.)

@JanusBahsJacquet Could you write up your comments as an answer?

Your gloss is correct. When has adding information to any kind of analysis "wrong"? The point is not the tense. The point is that in Spanish you have hunger and in English you are hungry.
